# CompletableFuture: control http response status-codes

Tags: spring-mvc, asynchronous, spring-boot

I'm currently struggeling returning http response status-codes on certain conditions. Let's say, the return objetct of taskService.getNewTasks is null. In this case I want to return status-code 404. On some exception I want to return some 50x, and so on.

My code so far

```
@RestController
public class TaskController {

  @Autowired
  private TaskService taskService;

  @GetMapping(path = "gettasks")
  private Future<Tasks> getNewTasks() {
    return taskService.getNewTasks();
  }
  ...
}

@Service
public class TaskService {

  @Async
  public Future<Tasks> getNewTasks() {
    ...
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(tasks);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types, `Future` isn’t supported as return type for controller handler methods.
Since you’re using `CompletableFuture` you can just return that or `CompletionStage`, which are supported by spring.
If that completes with an exception, you can use the regular Spring exception handling mechanisms like annotating the exception with `@ResponseStatus` .

Comment: There could be situation where you want to return other 200 status codes like 201.

Answer (score 8):

This could suit you.

```
@GetMapping(path = "gettasks")
private CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Tasks>> getNewTasks() {
  CompletableFuture<Tasks> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
  future.complete(taskService.getNewTasks());
  if(yourCondition){
    return future.thenApply(result -> new ResponseEntity<Tasks>(result, HttpStatus.STATUS_1));
  }
  return future.thenApply(result -> new ResponseEntity<Tasks>(result, HttpStatus.STATUS_2));
}
```